# Rescue not capturing failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm missing something here, but for some reason my `begin` then `rescue` Ruby code isn't capturing this error:

`#<ActiveResource::ResourceInvalid: Failed.  Response code = 422.  Response message = Unprocessable Entity.>`

This is my code:

```
begin
 ShopifyAPI::CarrierService.create(with some arguments)
rescue StandardError => e
  pp e
end
```

It doesn't ever capture it. In my `rescue` section I've tried the above but also:

```
 rescue Exception => e
 rescue ActiveResource::Errors => e
```

All with no luck. Where did I go astray?

Thanks

EDIT:
This is the full error, it not really anymore info, but here goes:

```
#<ShopifyAPI::CarrierService:0x0000000357a0a0
 @attributes=
  {"name"=>"XXXX",
   "callback_url"=>
    "https://XX-XX-XX-XX.c9users.io/receive_rate_request",
   "format"=>"json",
   "service_discovery"=>"true",
   "carrier_service_type"=>"api"},
 @errors=
  #<ActiveResource::Errors:0x00000003578930
   @base=#<ShopifyAPI::CarrierService:0x0000000357a0a0 ...>,
   @messages={:base=>["you already have XXX set up for this shop"]}>,
 @persisted=false,
 @prefix_options={},
 @remote_errors=
  #<ActiveResource::ResourceInvalid: Failed.  Response code = 422.  Response message = Unprocessable Entity.>,
 @validation_context=nil>
```

That's it!

Comment: Where are you seeing that error message? In your logs? It could be that you aren't getting an exception from ShopifyAPI::CarrierService.create and the error message is leading you to believe you are.  rescue Exception should catch everything.

Comment: Does the stacktrace actually point to that line of code? maybe the exception is not raised there, follow the stacktrace in case you are looking the wrong line

Comment: @arieljuod good question, I went ahead and updated the OP with the entire error message. It doesn't point to any line of code actually, just says the service already exists.

Comment: @bkimble hmm, and yes its in my logs. Where else could the error come from?

Comment: Check this error "@messages={:base=>["you already have XXX set up for this shop"]}>,", some validation is making the object invalid

Answer (score 3):

Because it is not raising an exception, If you want to raise the exception when the response is false, you may have to use create with bang

```
begin
 ShopifyAPI::CarrierService.create!(with some arguments)
rescue StandardError => e
  pp e
end
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the ActiveResource code (lib/active_resource/base.rb):

```
# <tt>404</tt> is just one of the HTTP error response codes that Active Resource will handle with its own exception. The
# following HTTP response codes will also result in these exceptions:
#
# * 200..399 - Valid response. No exceptions, other than these redirects:
# * 301, 302, 303, 307 - ActiveResource::Redirection
# * 400 - ActiveResource::BadRequest
# * 401 - ActiveResource::UnauthorizedAccess
# * 403 - ActiveResource::ForbiddenAccess
# * 404 - ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound
...
# * 422 - ActiveResource::ResourceInvalid (rescued by save as validation errors)
```

So it indicates that 422's are rescued by save on validation, which happens when .create is fired, and are bubbled up as validation errors instead.

Looking at lib/active_resource/validations.rb, you can see the ResourceInvalid exception is gobbled:

```
# Validate a resource and save (POST) it to the remote web service.
# If any local validations fail - the save (POST) will not be attempted.
def save_with_validation(options={})
  perform_validation = options[:validate] != false

  # clear the remote validations so they don't interfere with the local
  # ones. Otherwise we get an endless loop and can never change the
  # fields so as to make the resource valid.
  @remote_errors = nil
  if perform_validation && valid? || !perform_validation
    save_without_validation
    true
  else
    false
  end
rescue ResourceInvalid => error
  # cache the remote errors because every call to <tt>valid?</tt> clears
  # all errors. We must keep a copy to add these back after local
  # validations.
  @remote_errors = error
  load_remote_errors(@remote_errors, true)
  false
end
```

So I wonder if it's logging that an exception happened, but is not actually raising an exception because it turns it in to a return false. It does say "local validations" in the comment, but sets remote_errors, so it's not perfectly clear where this code path is executed.